# Why does unified_diff method from the difflib library in Python leave out some characters?

Tags: python, difflib, unified-diff

I am trying to check for differences between lines. This is my code:

```
from difflib import unified_diff

s1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
s2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'i', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n']

for line in unified_diff(s1, s2):
    print line
```

It prints:

```
---
+++ 

@@ -4,3 +4,9 @@

 d
 e
 f
+g
+i
+k
+l
+m
+n
```

What happened to 'a', 'b', and 'c'? Thanks!

Comment: They didn't change, so there's no reason to show them.

Comment: But why do 'd', 'e', and 'f' show?

Comment: To give context to the diff. Normally you'd do this with text or code, where it's useful to see the lines leading up to the changed ones.

Comment: if you do this instead: `for line in unified_diff(s1, s2, n=0):` , where `n=0` for no context, then output for `d`, `e`, and `f` will no longer show

Answer (score 8):

If you take a look at `unified_diff` code you will find description about a parameter called `n`:

> Unified diffs are a compact way of showing line changes and a few
> lines of context.  The number of context lines is set by 'n' which
> defaults to three.

In your case, `n` basically indicates numbers of characters. If you assign a value to `n`, then you will get the correct output. This code:

```
from difflib import unified_diff

s1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
s2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'i', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n']

for line in unified_diff(s1, s2,n=6):
    print line
```

Will generate:

```
--- 

+++ 

@@ -1,6 +1,12 @@

 a
 b
 c
 d
 e
 f
+g
+i
+k
+l
+m
+n
```